# C++ pure virtual functions implementation in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I have a **top** API (based on abstract class) which is composed by a **base** API (that will be reused by different **top** APIs).

```
class api_base {
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class api_top : public api_base {
public:
    virtual int bar() = 0;
}
```

Then, I want to provide a base implementation for base API:

```
class imp_base {
public:
    int foo() { return 1; }
}
```

And finally implement **top** API using base implementation for those functions defined in base API:

```
class imp_top : public api_top, public imp_base {
public:
    int bar() { return 1; }
}
```

When I instantiate an object of `imp_top` type, compiler say that `foo()` function is not implemented. But that is not true, since `imp_top` derives from `imp_base`, which do have `foo()` function implemented.

Any advice about this?

Thank you in advance.

Full test code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    class api_base { 
    public:
        virtual int foo() = 0;
    };

    class api_top : public api_base { 
    public:
        virtual int bar() = 0;
    };

    class imp_base { 
    public:
        int foo() { printf("foo from imp_base\n"); } 
    };

    class imp_top : public api_top, public imp_base { 
    public:
        int bar() { printf("bar from imp_top\n"); } 
    };

    int main()
    { 
       printf("Hello\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       imp_top a;

       a.bar();
       a.foo();

       return 1;
    }
```

Compiler result:

```
    test.cpp:26:12: error: cannot declare variable ‘a’ to be of abstract type ‘imp_top’                                                                                                                                                                                     
        imp_top a;
                ^
    test.cpp:18:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘imp_top’:
     class imp_top : public api_top, public imp_base {
           ^
    test.cpp:5:17: note:  virtual int api_base::foo()
         virtual int foo() = 0;
                     ^
    test.cpp:29:6: error: request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous
        a.foo();
          ^
    test.cpp:15:9: note: candidates are: int imp_base::foo()
         int foo() { printf("foo from imp_base\n"); }
             ^
    test.cpp:5:17: note:                 virtual int api_base::foo()
         virtual int foo() = 0;
```

Comment: `api_top` should have an implementation of `foo()`

Comment: Which version of C++ standard are you using?

Comment: @RX_DID_RX Any version of C++ that is not Java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`class api_top : public api_base` to `class api_top : public virtual api_base`

and:

`class imp_base` to `class imp_base : public virtual api_base`

Then it works.

To understand this, see: [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).  And yes (just saw Ext3h's post), use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

First Always use `override` keyword when redefining the functions in child classes.

Second read about virtual inheritance.

The following works :

```
class api_base {
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class api_top : public virtual api_base {
public:
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

class imp_base : public virtual api_base {
public:
    int foo() override { printf("foo from imp_base\n"); return 0; }
};

class imp_top : public api_top, public imp_base {
public:
    int bar() override { printf("bar from imp_top\n"); return 0; }
};


int main(){
    imp_top a;

    a.bar();
    a.foo();
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the `override` keyword, then you would had noticed that you did not implement the interface but defined an entirely new `foo()` method.

You will need to derive both `imp_base` and `api_top` from `api_base` by virtual inheritance.